# Can I get count of all Users on Facebook who have taken a Custom Action?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There are now Custom Actions in Facebook iFrame/Canvas. So one can create a basic verb/object pairing for their application. For example, I could create a "cook recipe" pair and have this show up in a variety of places in the user's profile.

I can access these custom actions using /me/activities in the Open Graph API. I would like to know if there is anyway that I can get a count of all users who have taken the action I created.

Apologies in advance, I am new to Faceboook development, so I am not 100% clear on some of the finer points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not possible via the API. But keep an eye on the Insights API (/app/insights) as this should eventually be updated to include monthly per-action stats. These stats are already available in the insights dashboard for your app.

However, as you're posting the actions to Facebook yourself, you should be able to keep a count locally in your app.